Assigning data in 4D list in python
I'm trying to assign data in a 4D list in python 3 but I'm struggling to understand the process. I have the following list and when I try to assign fs_list[0][0][0][0] to some value, then actually it is not only fs_list[0][0][0][0] updated, but also fs_list[0][0][1][0] , fs_list[0][0][2][0]  , fs_list[0][0][3][0] ...
What am I doing wrong?
>>> n_bg = 1
>>> n_cr = 8
>>> n_bg_p = 4
>>> n_cr_p = 6
>>> fs_list = [[[[None]*n_bg_p]*n_cr]*n_bg_p]*n_bg
>>> fs_list[0][0]
[[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None]]
>>> fs_list[0][0][0][0]='var1'
>>> fs_list[0][0]
[['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None], ['var1', None, None, None]]
>>> fs_list[0][0][1][0]='var2'
>>> fs_list[0][0]
[['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None], ['var2', None, None, None]]


